# Convert from dateTime string to javascript date object

Tags: javascript, regex

I use this method in order to convert a date string to a javascript date object:

```
function convertToDateOrUndefined(dateString) {
    if (dateString instanceof Date || dateString == null) { 
        return undefined;
    }
    return new Date(dateString.replace(/(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4})/,'$3-$2-$1'));
}
```

Currently I have this dateTime string 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm' and I would need also a function to convert this string into a js date obejct.
I am not really good in regex therefore I would need help - Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Look at the current regex. You know it returns a date from your `dd.MM.yyyy` format, right? So you can assume that the three `(\d{n})` represent the day, month and year (`\d` means a digit, `{n}` means `n` times, so `\d{2}` mean two digits; the `()` groups each part so we can refer to them later).

In the second string, we take the parts the we got from the 1st one, and reorder them. `$1` is the 1st group (the part of the regex inside the `()`), `$2` is the 2nd group, etc.

From there, the way to the solution is simple. We just need to add the time part:

```
new Date(dateString.replace(/(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4}) (\d{2}):(\d{2})/,'$3-$2-$1 $4:$5'));
```

Answer (score 0):

A non `regex` solution. Hope this helps

```js
var dateString = '25.12.2016 00:00';
var formattedDateString  = dateString.split(' ')[0].split('.').reverse().join('-');

var dateObj = new Date(formattedDateString);

console.log(dateObj);
```